# How to loop through child elements and create nested array of objects?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have nested checkboxes inside a `<ul>` / `<li>` list which can have as parent checkbox with `.check-negozio` class. Inside that parent there could be some checkboxes with `.check-cassa` class and those could contain other children checkboxes signed with `.check-operatore`

So html structure is the following and there could be various `<li>` with `.check-negozio` as parent

Now i need to build an object that will be as the following

```
[{ negozio: npv, cassa: [{ cassa: cs, operatore: [] }] }]
```

so from the example below, the object must look like this

```
[{ negozio: 0, cassa: [{ cassa: 1, operatore: [] }, { cassa: 5, operatore: [0]}] }]
```

To achieve this, I must loop through each `.check-negozio` then inside same loop I have to loop through that `.check-negozio` children `.check-cassa` and if the `.check-cassa` has children `.check-operator` loop through them.

I was trying to do the following but `$(this).children(".check-cassa").each` seems to be the wrong approach as it doesn't even enter inside that loop... how should I loop through nested elements like this?

```js
$(".check-negozio").each(function() {
  if (this.checked || this.indeterminate) { // if parent checkbox is checked add it to object

    const npv = $(this).attr('data-npv');
    selezione.negozio = npv;

    $(this).children(".check-cassa").each(function() { // here i should loop throw children .check-cassa of .check-negozio
      if (this.checked || this.indeterminate) { // if check-cassa is checked go ahead
        const cs = $(this).attr('data-cs');

        if ($(this).closest('li').has('ul').length) { // here i check if check-cassa contain any child (in this case check-operatore)

          $(this).children(".check-operatore").each(function() { // if there are child check-operatore loop throw them
            if (this.checked) { // if checked add data-op inside array of operatore
              const op = $(this).attr('data-op');
              operatore.push({
                OP: op
              });
            }
          })
          selezione.cassa.push({
            CS: cs,
            OP: operatore
          }) // here i add data-cs and array operatore inside object
        } else { // else if there isn't any child check-operatore just add data-cs with empty array of operatore
          selezione.cassa.push({
            CS: cs,
            OP: []
          });
        }
      }
    })
    config.push(selezione); // adding created object inside array
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" class="check-negozio" data-npv="0">
    <ul>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <input type="checkbox" class="check-cassa" data-cs="1">
      </li>
      <li>
        <input type="checkbox" class="check-cassa" data-cs="5">
        <ul>
          <li>
            <input type="checkbox" class="check-operatore" data-op="0">
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: The element with class `check_negozio` is an input element with no children. `check_cassa` and `check_operatore` elements are children of `li` and `ul`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the wrong approach was as @vqf said in comments is to loop throw `.check-cassa` by using `.check-negozio` as parent when i had to get firstly the parent of `.check-negozio` and then loop throw it's children `.check-cassa` i used the same approach where i was trying to loop throw `.check-operatore` firstly i get parent of `.check-cassa` and then looped throw it's children `.check-operatore` then i made some adjustment for get the right array of object by initializing object and arrays for `check-casse` and `check-operatori` inside the parent loop

here is the working code

```
var config = [];


$(".check-negozio").each(function () {
    var selezione = {};
    var cassa = [];
    var operatore = [];
    if (this.checked || this.indeterminate) { // if parent checkbox is checked add it to object

        const npv = $(this).attr('data-npv');
        selezione.NPV = npv;

        $(".check-cassa", $(this).parent()).each(function () { // here i should loop throw children .check-cassa of .check-negozio
            if (this.checked || this.indeterminate) { // if check-cassa is checked go ahead
                const cs = $(this).attr('data-cs');

                if ($(this).closest('li').has('ul').length) { // here i check if check-cassa contain any child (in this case check-operatore)

                    $(".check-operatore", $(this).parent()).each(function () { // if there are child check-operatore loop throw them
                        if (this.checked) { // if checked add data-op inside array of operatore
                            const op = $(this).attr('data-op');
                            operatore.push({ OP: op });
                        }
                    })
                    cassa.push({ CS: cs, OP: operatore }) // here i add data-cs and array operatore inside object
                } else { // else if there isn't any child check-operatore just add data-cs with empty array of operatore
                    cassa.push({ CS: cs, OP: [] });
                }
                selezione.cassa = cassa;
            }
        })
        config.push(selezione); // adding created object inside array
    }
})
```